# If ΔABC and ΔDEF are triangles, ∠ABC ≅ ∠DEF, ∠BCA ≅ ∠EFD, segments AB ≅ DE, then ΔABC ≅ ΔDEF.

Tags: proof-explanation, plane-geometry

If ΔABC and ΔDEF are triangles, ∠ABC ≅ ∠DEF, ∠BCA ≅ ∠EFD, segments AB ≅ DE, then ΔABC ≅ ΔDEF.

I was given the hint to use contradiction.

Assume ∠CAB not congruent to ∠FDE.

Without loss of generality, μ(∠CAB) < μ(∠FDE)

There is a point G on same side of line DE as F so that μ(∠EDG)=μ(∠CAB), by protractor postulate (angle construction)

By betweenness theorem for rays, ray DG is between ray DE and ray DF.

so ray DG meets segment EF at say H, by crossbar theorem.

Now from here i kind of get lost..

Comment: The sum of the angles is the same in both triangles, so you know the triangles are similar. No need to assume the last angle has different measure. You should know it doesn't.

Comment: so you're saying i shouldn't prove this with contradiction?? for some reason this is the way my professor wanted us to do it..

Comment: You could go with contradiction, but inequality of the last two angles is the wrong thing to assume, since it's immediately disprovable without actually getting you closer to a finished result.

Answer (score 1):

just observe that triangles are similar and one pair of lines is equal hence triangles are ongruent

Comment: I don't think this is a theorem. Take a $30, 60, 90$ triangle and scale up by a factor of two; they are similar, and one pair of side lengths are the same.

Comment: side pair must be in corresponding pair